# finding nth prime in python

Tags: python, primes

I wrote the following segment of code in Python to find the nth number. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can you please only give me a hint or point out exactly which bit is messing it up rather than a complete solution.

```
term = int(input("What prime do you want to find?   "))
prime_list=[2]

def prime_search(term):
    x=3
    while len(prime_list) <= term:
        if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2,x)):
            prime_list.append(x)
        x += 1
    return prime_list[term-1]

prime_search(term)
```

Comment: Can you please only give us a hint or point out exactly _how_ this code actually works and how its behavior is different from the one _you expect_?

Comment: print prime_search(term)

Comment: Your code is not optimal but it does what you expect, what is the problem ?

Comment: Is it just that you need a print statement to see the result!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dont `print` anything. Your function works.

```
term = int(input("What prime do you want to find?   "))
prime_list=[2]

def prime_search(term):
    x=3
    while len(prime_list) <= term:
        if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2,x)):
            prime_list.append(x)
        x += 1
    return prime_list[term-1]

print(prime_search(term))
```

Output:

```
What prime do you want to find?   5
11
```

However i advise you to look up prime sieve if you really want to use this.

Comment: thank you and everyone who commented above! can you advise me as to why the `x += 1' section of code needs to be alligned with the if statement rather than alligned with the prime_list.append?

Comment: Because you want to check all positive numbers. If you only increment it if you find a prime, your iteration will stop at the very first time it find a non-prime number, as you will not increment x (the i statement will always evaluate false, and x will stay the same)

Comment: ah thank you very much. i will check the seive method.